# Subject field is empty

Tags: exm

We are using an Email Experience Manager (EXM) on a current project. After applying new design (we added new layout and list of renderings to the presentaion of email), we’ve got an issue with **subject field**. Every time when we try to fill and save it (using EXM’s interface), it always appears empty and email can’t be send (“The message status has been changed to 'Paused'” message is shown).

Do you have any idea why it happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EXM checks if email has the “Set Page Title” rendering (/sitecore/layout/Renderings/Email Campaign/Set Page Title) at the presentation. And if it is not, EXM will skip subject and leave it empty. As a result, EXM throws the exception.

You need to add the “Set Page Title” rendering to the presentation and the issue will be solved. The “Set Page Title” rendering has to be added between the `<head></head>` tags.

Please, take into account that the  rendering have to be  added at the **Shared Layout**. If it is added to the Final Layout, it will not work.

Answer (score 3):

Usually such issues with email subject are caused by the incorrectly added 'Set Page Title' rendering (/sitecore/layout/Renderings/Email Campaign/Set Page Title).

Please make sure that your message layout doesn't have the  tag in the  section, but instead there is a placeholder, and the rendering is added to this placeholder:

```
 <head>
   <title>your custom title</title>
   <sc:Placeholder Key="msg-html-title" runat="server" />
    ....
 </head>
```

Please read this article : https://doc.sitecore.net/email_experience_manager/33/configuring_messages/types_and_templates/walkthrough_building_a_custom_message_template

The 'Set Page Title' control is mentioned in the article.

This control is used to ensure that message subject is used as page title in online version of the email - it is important that title and subject have the same value.