# EXM placeholders supporting only XSL renderings?

Tags: exm

Does exm only support xsl rendering for placeholders ? 
If yes what is the best way to build an email template from like 8 different components? Which are html based.

I am using EXM 3.5.0 170810 (the newest and the greatest)

Comment: Don't use Xslt, it's a nighmare for your client and for your project.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can create your own rendering in MVC or Webforms. To start with, you can install Sample Newsletter package which come as optional package in EXM installation. If you check Sitecore branch templates for EXM, you can follow similar principles to develop your own renderings, layout and placceholders in EXM.

For step by step instruction, you can refer below documentation

https://doc.sitecore.net/email_experience_manager/configuring_messages/types_and_templates/walkthrough_building_a_custom_message_template

Comment: Okay, I have followed these instructions, but only got a webform, thought cannot create a mvc one... Need to try that out. But still the Newsletter will be webform ?

Comment: Newsletter sample is created using both Webforms and MVC.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your message with Sitecore MVC instead of xslt. The same steps as for create page:

- create layout for message
- split your message template to separate small components
- create components
- add placeholders
  ... etc.

Don’t forgot about to add `Set Page title` rendering [link](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/5592/exm-subject-field-is-empty)