# Unable to set the Subject line even with 'Set Page Title' Rendering

Tags: exm

I am trying to set up a campaign in EXM to send an email based on a Sitecore page. However, when I get to the message part I am unable to set the subject line.

[image]

I have added the "Set Page Title" rendering up on the presentation of the item.

[image]

and I have this code in my view.

```
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
 @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("mn-title")
</head>`
```

But I am still unable to set the subject line. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Existing Page" EXM template uses the target page's browser title (i.e.`<html><head><title>...`) to determine the email's subject. Is it possible that you aren't outputting a title for this page?

In any case, I don't believe that the `Set Page Title` rendering is intended to be placed on to items in your content tree. [Sitecore documentation](https://doc.sitecore.net/email_experience_manager/configuring_messages/types_and_templates/walkthrough_building_a_custom_message_template) has you place it on the message root's presentation details (ex: `/sitecore/templates/Branches/System/Email Campaign/Messages/Custom newsletter/Monthly newsletter/Name/Message root`).

The `Set Page Title` rendering is an Xsl Rendering that points to `/xsl/EmailCampaign/Set Page Title.xslt` in your webroot. This file simply renders the "Subject" field off the email message item.

Comment: You are indeed correct. It just needs a title field. This thread about [EXM Subject Field blank](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/5592/exm-subject-field-is-empty) sent me off in the wrong direction. Thanks for the correction!